# SSIS dBASE IV OLEDB source error

Tags: sql-server, ssis, oledb, etl, dbase

The package that I am working on moves data from a .DBF file onto a table on SQL server.

I used provider for the source as Microsoft Jet 4.0 OLE DB Provider and set extended properties in the all tab of the connection manager to "dBASE IV".
(which is required for .DBF files - pulled this information while building package)

[image]

[image]

I have given environments - DEV, QA and PROD and have created project parameters to access respective paths.

For the source, went into properties and gave an expression to pick up filepath for respective servers (DEV, QA and PROD) and ran into below error while running the package.

> The connection string format is not valid. It must consist of one or more components of the form X=Y, separated by semicolons. This error occurs when a connection string with zero components is set on database connection manager.

[image]

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this [article](https://www.connectionstrings.com/dbf-foxpro/), the DBF connection string is like the following:

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=c:\folder;Extended Properties=dBASE IV;User ID=Admin;Password=;
```

You have to specify the folder that contains the database not the .DBF file

**Additional Information**

- [SSIS Connect to a dBASE or Other DBF File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/connection-manager/connect-to-a-dbase-or-other-dbf-file)
- [Importing dBF files to SQL Server using SSIS](https://simonsuthers.wordpress.com/2013/05/20/importing-dbf-files-to-sql-server-using-ssis/)

Comment: Thanks much...I have tried it for dev and it worked...need to deploy onto QA and see. Thanks a lot...have been scratching my head since couple of days.

Comment: @tanu if this solved your problem you have to accept the answer. Click on the mark below the voting arrows